# возвращаемое значение rvalue-reference

Tags: c++, rvalue

```
int n() {// rvalue returns
    int b = 9;
    return b;
}

int& n1() {// lvalue-ref=lvalue expr
    int b = 9;
    return b;
}

int&& n2() {// rvalue-ref=rvalue expr
    return 9;
}

int main(){
   int y=200;

   n1() = y;// почему здесь rvalue можно присвоить
 
   n2() = 8;// а тут rvalue 

   n() = 0;// и тут rvalue уже нельзя присвоить
   int&& v = 8;}
```

Из функций получается всегда возвращаются rvalue значения, тк без имени, но которые могут быть разных типов. Почему так непонятно работает?

Comment: 'n1() = 8;' — тут не rvalue, но в данном случае это сути не меняет: так присваивать все равно нельзя, это ссылка на локальную переменную...

Comment: @Harry а почему нет, ведь это объект без имени, следовательно rvalue?

Comment: Даже в случае, когда возвращается lvalue reference пример не работает, так как ссылка возвращается битая. *объект без имени, следовательно rvalue* - это вы сами придумали такое?

Comment: Куда важнее, что это объект *с адресом*... Только вот адрес этот теперь указывает в никуда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ваши функции `n1` и `n2` возвращают битые ссылки, потому что объекты, на которые они указывают, умирают при выходе из функции.

Поэтому тот вариант присваивания, который компилируется, все равно вызывает неопределенное поведение.

---

> Из функций получается всегда возвращаются rvalue значения, тк без имени

Неверно. Правило работает наоборот: любое имя - lvalue. Но бывают lvalue и без имен.

`n1()` возвращает lvalue.

`n()` и `n2()` возвращают rvalue. (Eсли точнее, они возвращают prvalue и xvalue соотвественно - это два подвида rvalue. Но здесь между ними похоже нет никакой разницы.)

---

Как в этом убедиться? [Вот так.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:67,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:67,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:67,selectionStartLineNumber:32,startColumn:67,startLineNumber:32),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+PrintType()%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C%0A++++%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A++++__FUNCSIG__%0A++++%23else%0A++++__PRETTY_FUNCTION__%0A++++%23endif%0A++++%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+n()+%7B//+rvalue+returns%0A++++int+b+%3D+9%3B%0A++++return+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint%26+n1()+%7B//+lvalue-ref%3Dlvalue+expr%0A++++int+b+%3D+9%3B%0A++++return+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint%26%26+n2()+%7B//+rvalue-ref%3Drvalue+expr%0A++++return+9%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A+++PrintType%3Cdecltype((n()))%3E()%3B+//+void+PrintType()+%5BT+%3D+int%5D%0A+++PrintType%3Cdecltype((n1()))%3E()%3B+//+void+PrintType()+%5BT+%3D+int+%26%5D%0A+++PrintType%3Cdecltype((n2()))%3E()%3B+//+void+PrintType()+%5BT+%3D+int+%26%26%5D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.22570909891783,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,paneName:Clang,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:Clang,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:46.40234948604993,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:13,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,paneName:%27Clang+output%27,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Clang+output%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:53.59765051395007,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.77429090108217,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void PrintType()
{
    std::cout <<
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    __FUNCSIG__
    #else
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #endif
    << '\n';
}
```

```
PrintType<decltype((n()))>(); // void PrintType() [T = int]
PrintType<decltype((n1()))>(); // void PrintType() [T = int &]
PrintType<decltype((n2()))>(); // void PrintType() [T = int &&]
```

А дальше считаете амперсанды в выводе.   = prvalue, `&` = lvalue, `&&` = xvalue.

Обратите внимание на двойные скобки после `decltype`. Здесь они не влияют на ответ, но в других случаях могут влиять. (Например, `int &&x = 42;`, `decltype(x)` = `int &&`, но `decltype((x)) = int &`. Здесь `x`, как ни странно, lvalue, ведь у него есть имя.)

---

Из вашего примера можно сделать вывод, что rvalue нельзя ничего присваивать, а lvalue можно.

Но в общем случае это **не** так. Это верно только для [скалярных типов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ScalarType) (т.е. целых и дробных чисел, enum-ов, указателей, и т.п.). А классам можно присваивать всегда (если только создатель класса это явно не запретил).

Вывод - такой запрет - это искусственное ограничение, защита от выстрела себе в ногу. У lvalue, как и у rvalue, есть адреса. То, что у rvalue нельзя его взять напрямую - это тоже защита от дурака.

(Тут еще нужно объяснение про то, что у prvalue строго говоря адресов нет, и это вообще не объекты - но это занудство, и тут не влияет на результат. Можете почитать про mandatory copy elision.)

---

> `int&& v = 8;`

У меня ощущение, что тут был немой вопрос - "как здесь получилось присвоить rvalue?".

Ответ - это вообще не присваивание, это инициализация.

Присваиванием было бы `int &&v = 8; v = 42;`. А вот это компилируется, потому что `v` - lvalue (выше объяснил почему). Если превратить его в rvalue через `std::move`, то перестанет компилироваться: `std::move(v) = 42;`.

Answer (score 2):

Любые объекты, у которых закончилось время жизни теряют и ликвидность ссылки. Неважно `&` или `&&` - они уже битые. Единственным правильным способом передать умирающий объект остаётся только по значению.

```cpp
int& n1() {// lvalue-ref=lvalue expr
  int b = 9;
  // здесь b - lvalue
  return b;
  // здесь ссылка уже на битый объект
  // warning: reference to local variable 'b' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
}
```

Здесь компилятор разрешает передавать по l-value ссылке, так как иногда он бывает неспособен вычислить у какого объекта заканчивается время жизни, а если догадывается, то возвращает только предупреждение.

```cpp
int&& n2() {// rvalue-ref=rvalue expr
  // warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
  return 9;
}
```

То же самое здесь, значение по этой ссылке может и очень вероятно будет иметь совсем другое значение. r-ссылка не гарантирует жизнь объекту.
Если функция посложнее и компилятор не видит что объект передаётся уже с истёкшим сроком жизни, то тогда предупреждений не будет и всё зависит от алгоритма.

Если у объекта уже закончилось время жизни `r-value` ссылке можно подключить **только** `r-value` **объект** после получения значения из функции. И это называется продление жизни возвращаемому значению. *Но не r-ссылке.*

```cpp
int n() {// rvalue returns
    int b = 9;
    return b;
}
int main(){
  int && rv = n ( ) ;
  // ссылка rv живая
  ++ rv ;
  int && v = 8;
  // ссылка v живая
  ++ v ;
}
```

Чтобы оператор присваивания принимал изменения значения объекту нужно его привязать к переменной. Тогда это переменная как r-value ссылка будет иметь статус l-value.

```cpp
int main(){
  int && rv = n ( ) ;
  // ссылка rv живая, и она имеет статус l-value
  rv = 7 ;
  int && v = 8;
  // ссылка v живая, и она имеет статус l-value
  v = 77 ;
}
```